# Does the Cessna 152 or 172 have emergency door cable releases?

Tags: cessna-172, cessna-152, doors

Is there such a thing as an emergency cable release inside the cockpit of 152 or 172, to remove the door hinge pins in an emergency?

Answer (score 6):

The Cessna 150 Aerobat and 152 Aerobat both have jettisonable doors.

I don’t believe any version of the Cessna 172 does as there in no aerobatic C172 versions.

This Photo shows two “D” rings which are pulled to jettison the doors.
[image]

Comment: That's a nice blue sky you've got there, be a shame if something were to happen to it...